# Symfony2 - request not working on select

Tags: symfony

I have something strange going on which I can't figure out.  I have a normal HTML form, and inside this form I have a couple of things

```
<textarea id="na_command" name="na_command" rows="3" cols="50" ></textarea>

<select name="select" name="na_is_connecting" id="na_is_connecting">
    <option value="no" selected>No</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

My Model for these things is pretty straight forward,

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="search_command", type="string", length=256, nullable=false)
 */
private $searchCommand;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_connecting", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
 */
private $isConnecting;

/**
 * Set searchCommand
 *
 * @param string $searchCommand
 * @return AvailabilityAlert
 */
public function setSearchCommand($searchCommand)
{
    $this->searchCommand = $searchCommand;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set isConnecting
 *
 * @param string $isConnecting
 * @return AvailabilityAlert
 */
public function setIsConnecting($isConnecting)
{
    $this->isConnecting = $isConnecting;

    return $this;
}
```

Essentially, they are both strings - both the same.

However, in my controller, if I do

```
$alert = new AvailabilityAlert();
$alert->setSearchCommand($request->get('na_command'));
$alert->setIsConnecting($request->get('na_is_connecting'));
```

And I persist $alert to my database, I get the error

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO availability_alert (search_command, is_connecting) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["Testing", null]:

So it picks up na_command but it doesnt seem to pick up the value from my select na_is_connecting.

Is there anything in my code which is causing this to happen?  If I hard code a value for this select, it works fine.  I know with the form builder you can set a default value, is there something I need to do to set this without the form builder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've made a mistake in your html:

```
<select name="select" name="na_is_connecting"
```

You put the 'name' attribute twice.

Comment: Perfect.  I have had it running fine in normal HTML/PHP for ages, and it never complained once.  Good thing Symfony picked it up.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not at all. Glad to help